# How do I design a centered grid that consists of a 1x2 grid stacked on top of a 1x3 grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I know that I can use the TikZ package to create axb grids, but is there a way to create a more complicated grid like a 1x2 grid stacked on top of a 1x3 grid? For reference, I am interested in creating something like:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post your compilable code for the 1x3 grid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackon[-\fboxrule]{\fbox{C}\fbox{D}\fbox{E}}{\fbox{A}\fbox{B}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For something a bit more fancy...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\fcolorbox{blue!40!gray}{blue!10}{#1}\kern-\fboxrule}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\stackon[-\fboxrule]{\mybox{C}\mybox{D}\mybox{E}}{\mybox{A}\mybox{B}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With several `nx1` matrix, it's easy to make these constructions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}
\tikzset{
    myarray/.style={matrix, matrix of nodes, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={draw=blue!50, fill=blue!50!gray!20, font=\ttfamily, inner sep=.3333em, anchor=center,}}
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[myarray] (A) {A&B\\};
    \node[myarray, below=-\pgflinewidth of A] {C&D&E\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[myarray] (A) {A\\B\\};
    \node[myarray, right=-\pgflinewidth of A] {C\\D\\E\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]